# ListView Taking Up All of Screen Space

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to design a layout that has a listView and two buttons at bottom.

Layout XML looks something like this -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#ffffff">
      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
         android:id="@+id/previous"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="Previous"/>
    <Button
         android:id="@+id/next"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="Next"/>     
 </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

But the ListView Takes up all of screenspace, and buttons are not displayed.

The items in listview are generated dynamically, adapter used is ArrayAdapter.

A separate xml file that is a copy-paste of Android's simple_list_item_1.xml is passed to ArrayAdapter so the text displayed is black, and not light Grey.

Any workaround so the list is displayed with buttons at bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#ffffff">
     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_above="@+id/btnBar"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/btnBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/previous"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:text="Previous"/>
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/next"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:text="Next"/>     
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Lines that Matter Are the `RelativeLayout` As your Base `ViewGroup`, and this tells your `ListView` to stay above the bottom bar:

```
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnBar"
```

and this tells your button bar `LinearLayout` to pin to the bottom of the screen:

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Furthermore if you want the Buttons to take up Equal Space use:

```
   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/btnBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/previous"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Previous"/>
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/next"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Next"/>     
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Had to add android:layout_alignParentTop="true" in ListView, since the list with few elements was sticking to bottom of screen.